# Python, dictionary sum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary obtained as following:

```
test= {'Test': [sum(t) for t in zip(*data.values())],}
```

And suppose that the test values as the following:

```
test={ 'Test': [ t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 ] }
```

I want to obtain the following result:

```
results={ 'Test': [ r1=t1 , r2=r1+t2 , r3=r2+t3 , r4=r3+t4 , r5=r4+t5 ] }
```

And finally, if the results values are negative, set equal to zero.

How could I get it?

Comment: What are r1 and s1?

Comment: Isn't `r1=s1` supposed to be `r1=t1`?

Comment: Yep sorry, there was an misprint

Comment: You have overcomplicated your question by using a dictionary and by adding the [tag:django] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

```
import itertools

t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 = 1, 2, 4, -8, 16

test = {'Test': [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]}
test['Test'] = list(itertools.accumulate(test['Test']))

print(test)
```

This will give you `{'Test': [1, 3, 7, -1, 15]}`

The additional condition to set the final result to `0` if it's less than `0` can be done mith the `max` function.

```
test['Test'] = list(max(v, 0) for v in itertools.accumulate(test['Test']))
```

In that case we get `{'Test': [1, 3, 7, 0, 15]}`.

Comment: okey thanks, and If I want to have to set negativ values equal to zero?

Comment: Something like `test['Test'] = [i if i >= 0 else 0 for i in itertools.accumulate(test['Test'])]` would work. Actually I like the use of `max` more like @Matthias suggests. It makes it more readable.

Comment: @Axe319 That was the second option I considered.

Comment: Comment for future readers: Have a look at the `itertools` module in the Python standard library. It might seem to be difficult when you start working with it, but there is a great bunch of really useful stuff in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
# Initialize the result 'Test' list to access by indexes
result = {'Test': [0 for _ in test['Test']]}

# Note that we can't check if value is not 0 by using
# try-except IndexError statement, because index -1 exists
for index, value in enumerate(test['Test']):
    if index == 0:
        result['Test'][0] = test['Test'][0]
    else:
        result['Test'][index] = test['Test'][index] + result['Test'][index-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using *list comprehension*:

```
test = {'Test': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
result = [sum(test["Test"][:i]) + v for i, v in enumerate(test["Test"])]
result_non_negative = [0 if x<0 else x for x in result]
print({"Test": result_non_negative})
```